# Change requiring props if at lease on exist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types, interface

I've type:

```
export type ButtonProps = {
    href?: string;
    to?: string;
    link?: React.ElementType;
};
```

And when i use `<Button />` with this type and pass `to` or `href`, i want to change `link` to require prop. Like:

`if (href || to) then => link is required`

I tried add some generic type:

```
type RequireAtLeastOne<T, Keys extends keyof T = keyof T> =
    Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, Keys>> 
    & {
        [K in Keys]-?: Required<Pick<T, K>> & Partial<Pick<T, Exclude<Keys, K>>>
    }[Keys]
```

Which i find typescript interface require but it didn't help in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
export type ButtonProps = {
    to: string;
    link: string;
} | {
    href: string;
    link: string;
} | undefined


const props1: ButtonProps = {
  to: "asd", 
  link: "123"
};

const props2: ButtonProps = {
  href: "asd", 
  link: "123"
};

// Error
const props3: ButtonProps = {
  to: "asd", 
};

// Error
const props4: ButtonProps = {
  href: "asd", 
};
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBCBXGMIDsAKUEYAznALxwDeAUHPQhAFxwkxQCWuA5gNx0MANlwDWLNpx78AvnAA+1AfQAWUYADNx7LnyVxhuMa21SashRlwATDV2BWajgMZ42cMEVIBGFpmx5CYjJKWnocFgAiAEMSKwiAGjgBAyMIrwAmAGYIs34aF1w3DyD03ywcAk9gxRU1TTho2ISk+hTIjOzcxwB6brgAUSgiKHzXeGLSTLL-SqCKGsZImLjErppegaHoUcLxqoAWaYrA0nnQuFUNJabV6V4gA)

Comment: React will always pass a props object, and the type would need to account for it (`props` can't be `undefined`), so not sure this actually works for the OP's case?

Comment: to and href it not required, so i can't change it to a required prop. Also a have more then 10 prop (not only to and href) and it will too big tyoe

Comment: They are not required in this case. You just have to add the remaining props to all the cases. I'll edit it to add one required prop.

Comment: @nullptr - can we use it with interface too or only with type?